# How to make a toggle button default active as the page loads

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have these three bootstrap toggle buttons that alter the screen sizes according to requirement.

Now i been trying to make one of these buttons "active" defaultly as the page loads.

The code goes as :

```
<div class="vd_panel-menu hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-intro="<strong>Expand Control</strong><br/>" data-step=5  data-position="left">
    <div data-action="remove-navbar" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="remove-navbar-button menu"> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h" ></i> </div>
      <div data-action="remove-header" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="remove-header-button menu"> <i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i> </div>
      <div data-action="fullscreen" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="fullscreen-button menu"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i> </div>   
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Considering the first button and  assume it is been active which means your **Button Class** should look like this `class="remove-navbar-button menu active">`

`.active` is the default css of bootstrap  whenever you need to active the button  by default.you have to call that class by simply put `active`

[Bootstrap toggle](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#toggle-states)

Comment: I tried it, but it just makes the button dark in color as it been clicked but not active. i still have to click it to make it active...

Comment: oh. you may use <label> tag before button.

Comment: I tried this.... `<label class="active"><div data-action="remove-navbar" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="remove-navbar-button menu "> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h" ></i> </div></label>` yet didn't worked..

Comment: I can't figure out the exact reason for that. you should check the button action using dev tools. check the css code for button actions.